# AndroidManifest error

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm getting an error in my AndroidManifest file, "error parsing xml: junk after document" the IDE isn't highlighting the error but its flagging the error at "android:versionName="1.0">" 
Any ideas what's wrong??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trail"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher-web" android:label="@ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trai">
            <activity
                android:name="GPSActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </application>

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Checked there's no extra tags or other rubbish after the /manifest ?

Comment: maybe `android:label="@ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trai"` line causing issue

Comment: What could be wrong with this? Can you put any title in there or does it have to correspond with another value?

Comment: @user2083702 try my idea.it may help you..

Comment: @TGMCians : OP need to change both first change drawable name according to ur answer and second either remove @ from front of String or add an key-value inside strings.xml and use `@string/keyname_for_App_level` instead of `android:label="@ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trai"`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I do agree with you..

Comment: Sorry I changed to android:label="@string/app_name" which is what i have in strings.xml, but that didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess it might be because of naming convention of image in res folder.
>
> **Naming convention** is  File name must contain only **[a-z0-9_.]**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher-web" android:label="@ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trai" > <!--Problem here-->...
```

- Rename this image in res folder to **ic_launcer_web** and here also.
- define one attribute in **strings.xml**

`<string name="app>GPS</string>`

and set like this in Android Manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_web" android:label="@string/app">
```

Comment: @user2083702 Please check the resources file like string.xml do not have any errors that also creates problem..

Comment: I tried your edit but that didnt work either, there's no errors in strings.xml

Comment: @user2083702 Make ensure you not have any error in resource file ex strings.xml

Comment: @user2083702 After this clean the project and then run it.

Comment: I'm having another problem now in my GPSActivity class, never mind I'll open a new question. Thanks for all yer help